# React Navigation 6 (RN6) - Card stack within a modal

Tags: react-navigation-v6

I have a question about a card stack inside a modal stack as illustrated in the attached image.

So, just to repeat what I wanted to do. I have a `screen` with the option `presentation: 'modal'` that opens the green modal.

Inside that green modal, I have a button that should invoke a navigation call that should show the blue `screen` with option `presentation: 'card'` and the ability to go back to the green screen.

[image]

I have done something similar with the react-native-navigation library from [WIX](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) but I have no idea if that can be done with react-navigation.

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution with `Nesting navigators` as described [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/)

Basically, I created a `ModalStack` and used this stack in `Screen` component as shown below.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import { TransitionPresets } from '@react-navigation/stack'

import HomeView from '../screens/HomeView'
import ModalView from '../screens/ModalView'
import CardView from '../screens/CardView'

const RootStack = createNativeStackNavigator()
const ModalStack = createNativeStackNavigator()

const ModalStackView = () => (
  <ModalStack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: true,
    }}>
    <ModalStack.Screen
      name="modalCard1"
      component={ModalView}
      options={{
        presentation: 'modal'
      }}
    />
    <ModalStack.Screen
      name="modalCard2"
      component={CardView}
      options={{
        presentation: 'card'
      }}
    />
  </ModalStack.Navigator>
)

const Stacks = () => (
  <RootStack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}>
    <RootStack.Screen name="home" component={HomeView} />
    <RootStack.Screen
      name="modal"
      component={ModalStackView}
      options={{
        presentation: 'modal'
      }}
    />
  </RootStack.Navigator>
)

export default Stacks
```

Here the [Snack with the full code](https://snack.expo.dev/@dittmarconsulting/rn6-card-in-modalstack)

Comment: not working for android

Comment: how to give modal height

Comment: Damn! This is the exact case that I had too, and this works 100% for me :) Thx <3